# does Bigquery BI engine works with partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-bi-engine

I have a small table in Bigquery less than 20 Mg, it is partitioned per date and has a cluster on 1 field and it does require filter Partition.

when i create a reservation, and connect using datastudio, I get the error is that the query is not Powered by BI engine, as the table has a big size ( which is not true).

what's causing the problem, is it the filter partition ?

Comment: BI Engine does support partitioned tables. Does it work when you apply filter on partitioned column? Also feel free to report issue for BigQuery in https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, it was a bug in BI Engine, fixed now

edit: it was a bug in BI engine, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140507651